# Perspective Transform in Skia

Tags: c#, transform, perspective, skia

I have a quadrilateral, the coordinates of which are known. I need to do a perspective transform and warp an image to those coordinates using Skia. I have referred to the links in Skia's page like https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/transforms/non-affine/ but not able to use the coordinates. How do I use the coordinates instead of matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that takes the coordinates of the four corners on the destination image and the size of the source image. It then generates a matrix that can be passed to skia:

```cs
public static SKMatrix CreateMatrixFromPoints(SKPoint topLeft, SKPoint topRight, SKPoint botRight, SKPoint botLeft, float width, float height)
{
    (float x1, float y1) = (topLeft.X, topLeft.Y);
    (float x2, float y2) = (topRight.X, topRight.Y);
    (float x3, float y3) = (botRight.X, botRight.Y);
    (float x4, float y4) = (botLeft.X, botLeft.Y);
    (float w, float h) = (width, height);

    float scaleX = (y1 * x2 * x4 - x1 * y2 * x4 + x1 * y3 * x4 - x2 * y3 * x4 - y1 * x2 * x3 + x1 * y2 * x3 - x1 * y4 * x3 + x2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * w + y2 * x4 * w - y3 * x4 * w - x2 * y4 * w - y2 * w * x3 + y4 * w * x3);
    float skewX = (-x1 * x2 * y3 - y1 * x2 * x4 + x2 * y3 * x4 + x1 * x2 * y4 + x1 * y2 * x3 + y1 * x4 * x3 - y2 * x4 * x3 - x1 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * h + y2 * x4 * h - y3 * x4 * h - x2 * y4 * h - y2 * h * x3 + y4 * h * x3);
    float transX = x1;
    float skewY = (-y1 * x2 * y3 + x1 * y2 * y3 + y1 * y3 * x4 - y2 * y3 * x4 + y1 * x2 * y4 - x1 * y2 * y4 - y1 * y4 * x3 + y2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * w + y2 * x4 * w - y3 * x4 * w - x2 * y4 * w - y2 * w * x3 + y4 * w * x3);
    float scaleY = (-y1 * x2 * y3 - y1 * y2 * x4 + y1 * y3 * x4 + x1 * y2 * y4 - x1 * y3 * y4 + x2 * y3 * y4 + y1 * y2 * x3 - y2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * h + y2 * x4 * h - y3 * x4 * h - x2 * y4 * h - y2 * h * x3 + y4 * h * x3);
    float transY = y1;
    float persp0 = (x1 * y3 - x2 * y3 + y1 * x4 - y2 * x4 - x1 * y4 + x2 * y4 - y1 * x3 + y2 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * w + y2 * x4 * w - y3 * x4 * w - x2 * y4 * w - y2 * w * x3 + y4 * w * x3);
    float persp1 = (-y1 * x2 + x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - y2 * x4 + y3 * x4 + x2 * y4 + y1 * x3 - y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * h + y2 * x4 * h - y3 * x4 * h - x2 * y4 * h - y2 * h * x3 + y4 * h * x3);
    float persp2 = 1;

    return new SKMatrix(scaleX, skewX, transX, skewY, scaleY, transY, persp0, persp1, persp2);
}
```

#### Here is how I got this function:

From the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/non-affine) you've linked, skia calculates the transformed coordinates like this:

```
x' = ScaleX·x + SkewX·y + TransX
y' = SkewY·x + ScaleY·y + TransY
z` = Persp0·x + Persp1·y + Persp2

xFinal = x' / z'
yFinal = y' / z'
```

where `(x, y)` is the original position of a pixel, `(xFinal, yFinal)` is its new position, and variations of `Scale/Skew/Trans/Persp` are the values from the supplied matrix.

First, let's slightly rewrite the formulas:

```
xFinal = (ScaleX·x + SkewX·y + TransX) / (Persp0·x + Persp1·y + Persp2)
yFinal = (SkewY·x + ScaleY·y + TransY) / (Persp0·x + Persp1·y + Persp2)
```

Given the position of the corners of the quadrilateral `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)`, `(x3,y3)`, `(x4,y4)` and the size of the image `(w,h)`, we need to find the values of `ScaleX`, `SkewX`, `TransX`, `SkewY`, `ScaleY`, `TransY`, `Persp0`, `Persp1`, and `Persp2` such that after applying the formulas above:

- `(0,0)` becomes `(x1,y1)` (image top left -> quadrilateral top left)
- `(w,0)` becomes `(x2,y2)` (image top right -> quadrilateral top right)
- `(w,h)` becomes `(x3,y3)` (image bottom right -> quadrilateral bottom right)
- `(0,h)` becomes `(x4,y4)` (image bottom left -> quadrilateral bottom left)

Now we can substitute `(x,y)` for `(0,0)`; `(w,0)`; `(w,h)`; `(0,h)` and `(xFinal,yFinal)` for `(x1,y1)`; `(x2,y2)`; `(x3,y3)`; `(x4,y4)`.

```
x1 = (ScaleX·0 + SkewX·0 + TransX) / (Persp0·0 + Persp1·0 + Persp2)
y1 = (SkewY·0 + ScaleY·0 + TransY) / (Persp0·0 + Persp1·0 + Persp2)

x2 = (ScaleX·w + SkewX·0 + TransX) / (Persp0·w + Persp1·0 + Persp2)
y2 = (SkewY·w + ScaleY·0 + TransY) / (Persp0·w + Persp1·0 + Persp2)

x3 = (ScaleX·w + SkewX·h + TransX) / (Persp0·w + Persp1·h + Persp2)
y3 = (SkewY·w + ScaleY·h + TransY) / (Persp0·w + Persp1·h + Persp2)

x4 = (ScaleX·0 + SkewX·h + TransX) / (Persp0·0 + Persp1·h + Persp2)
y4 = (SkewY·0 + ScaleY·h + TransY) / (Persp0·0 + Persp1·h + Persp2)
```

By simplifying and rearranging that, we end up with a system of linear equations.

```
x1·Persp2 - TransX = 0
y1·Persp2 - TransY = 0

Persp0·w·x2 + Persp2·x2 - ScaleX·w - TransX = 0
Persp0·w·y2 + Persp2·y2 - SkewY·w - TransY = 0

Persp0·w·x3 + Persp1·h·x3 + Persp2·x3 - ScaleX·w - SkewX·h - TransX = 0
Persp0·w·y3 + Persp1·h·y3 + Persp2·y3 - SkewY·w - ScaleY·h - TransY = 0

Persp1·h·x4 + Persp2·x4 - SkewX·h - TransX = 0
Persp1·h·y4 + Persp2·y4 - ScaleY·h - TransY = 0
```

All that's left is solving it for `ScaleX`, `SkewX`, `TransX`, `SkewY`, `ScaleY`, `TransY`, `Persp0`, `Persp1`, and `Persp2`. In other words, we want
to find a way to express these variables in terms of all the other ones which we know. I used [this](https://matrixcalc.org/en/slu.html) calculator to do the job. It's output are the formulas from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Python version of @Equbuxu’s answer:

```py
def create_matrix_from_points(top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left, width, height):
    x1, y1 = top_left.x, top_left.y
    x2, y2 = top_right.x, top_right.y
    x3, y3 = bottom_right.x, bottom_right.y
    x4, y4 = bottom_left.x, bottom_left.y

    scale_x = (y1 * x2 * x4 - x1 * y2 * x4 + x1 * y3 * x4 - x2 * y3 * x4 - y1 * x2 * x3 + x1 * y2 * x3 - x1 * y4 * x3 + x2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * width + y2 * x4 * width - y3 * x4 * width - x2 * y4 * width - y2 * width * x3 + y4 * width * x3)
    skew_x = (-x1 * x2 * y3 - y1 * x2 * x4 + x2 * y3 * x4 + x1 * x2 * y4 + x1 * y2 * x3 + y1 * x4 * x3 - y2 * x4 * x3 - x1 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * height + y2 * x4 * height - y3 * x4 * height - x2 * y4 * height - y2 * height * x3 + y4 * height * x3)
    translation_x = x1
    skew_y = (-y1 * x2 * y3 + x1 * y2 * y3 + y1 * y3 * x4 - y2 * y3 * x4 + y1 * x2 * y4 - x1 * y2 * y4 - y1 * y4 * x3 + y2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * width + y2 * x4 * width - y3 * x4 * width - x2 * y4 * width - y2 * width * x3 + y4 * width * x3)
    scale_y = (-y1 * x2 * y3 - y1 * y2 * x4 + y1 * y3 * x4 + x1 * y2 * y4 - x1 * y3 * y4 + x2 * y3 * y4 + y1 * y2 * x3 - y2 * y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * height + y2 * x4 * height - y3 * x4 * height - x2 * y4 * height - y2 * height * x3 + y4 * height * x3)
    translation_y = y1
    perspective0 = (x1 * y3 - x2 * y3 + y1 * x4 - y2 * x4 - x1 * y4 + x2 * y4 - y1 * x3 + y2 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * width + y2 * x4 * width - y3 * x4 * width - x2 * y4 * width - y2 * width * x3 + y4 * width * x3)
    perspective1 = (-y1 * x2 + x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - y2 * x4 + y3 * x4 + x2 * y4 + y1 * x3 - y4 * x3) / (x2 * y3 * height + y2 * x4 * height - y3 * x4 * height - x2 * y4 * height - y2 * height * x3 + y4 * height * x3)
    perspective2 = 1

    return skia.Matrix(scale_x, skew_x, translation_x, skew_y, scale_y, translation_y, perspective0, perspective1, perspective2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is specifically for C#, so you shouldn’t post an answer for a different language. If you like, you can ask a similar question for Python, and then post your own answer to that question in Python. That is the preferred way of handling situations like this on Stack Overflow. Can you do that?